# Выпадающий список в комбобоксе автоматически сворачивается

Tags: c++, qt5

Есть класс диалога для выбора типа маркера в контекстном меню. Диалог создается один раз и по мере необходимости делается видимым или прячется. При первом использовании в комбобоксе можно свободно выбрать любой пункт. При повторном вызове выпадающий список автоматически сворачивается. Выбрать элемент списка можно только вращая колесо мышки.

```
CMarkerDlg::CMarkerDlg( QWidget* parent ) : QDialog( parent )
{
    m_pui = new Ui::MarkerDialog;
    m_pui->setupUi(this);

    m_pui->cbMarkers->addItem(QIcon( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/Images/marker_wyhte.png" ), "" );
    m_pui->cbMarkers->addItem(QIcon( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/Images/marker_black.png" ), "" );
    m_pui->cbMarkers->addItem(QIcon( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/Images/marker_red.png" ), "" );
    m_pui->cbMarkers->addItem(QIcon( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/Images/marker_green.png" ), "" );
    m_pui->cbMarkers->addItem(QIcon( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/Images/marker_blue.png" ), "" );


    connect( m_pui->pbCancel, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));
    connect( m_pui->pbOk, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onOk()));
    hide();
}

void CMarkerDlg::onOk()
{
    CMarker NewMarker;
    NewMarker.pos = m_MarkerPos;
    NewMarker.pixmapID = m_pui->cbMarkers->currentIndex();
    switch ( NewMarker.pixmapID )
    {
        case 0: NewMarker.pixmap.load( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/Images/marker_wyhte.png" ); break;
        case 1: NewMarker.pixmap.load( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/Images/marker_black.png" ); break;
        case 2: NewMarker.pixmap.load( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/Images/marker_red.png" ); break;
        case 3: NewMarker.pixmap.load( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/Images/marker_green.png" ); break;
        case 4: NewMarker.pixmap.load( QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/Images/marker_blue.png" ); break;
    }
    NewMarker.comment = m_pui->textEdit->toPlainText();;
    m_pui->textEdit->clear();
    emit onSetMarker( NewMarker );
    hide();
}
```

Comment: Обработку изменения текущего элемента комбобокса покажите

Comment: Не совсем понял, что имеется ввиду. Специальной обработки нет. Используется текущий выбранный индекс в списке.     NewMarker.pixmapID = m_pui->cbMarkers->currentIndex();

Comment: Данных из вопроса недостаточно для решения проблемы. Покажите минимальный воспроизводимый пример